# Implementing sleep function using signal handler

Tags: linux, signals, sigaction

In APUE, section 10.19 (sleep, nanosleep, ...), we have an implementation for **sleep** function. About line 11, there exists the following code

```
/* block SIGALRM and save current signal mask */
sigemptyset(&newmask);
sigaddset(&newmask, SIGALRM);
sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &newmask, &oldmask);
```

My question is: what will happen, if we we don't block SIGALRM?

full code is as follows:

```
sleep(unsigned int seconds)
{
struct sigaction newact, oldact;
sigset_t newmask, oldmask, suspmask;
unsigned int unslept;


/* set our handler, save previous information */
newact.sa_handler = sig_alrm;
sigemptyset(&newact.sa_mask);
newact.sa_flags = 0;
sigaction(SIGALRM, &newact, &oldact);

/* block SIGALRM and save current signal mask */
sigemptyset(&newmask);
sigaddset(&newmask, SIGALRM);
sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &newmask, &oldmask);
alarm(seconds);
suspmask = oldmask;

/* make sure SIGALRM isn’t blocked */
sigdelset(&suspmask, SIGALRM);

/* wait for any signal to be caught */
sigsuspend(&suspmask);

/* some signal has been caught, SIGALRM is now blocked */
unslept = alarm(0);

/* reset previous action */
sigaction(SIGALRM, &oldact, NULL);

/* reset signal mask, which unblocks SIGALRM */
sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, &oldmask, NULL);
return(unslept);
}
```

Comment: What's the rest of the code?

Comment: SIGALRM handler will be invoked. Default SIGALRM handler terminates process.

Comment: But, SIGALRM, was catched in the first part

Comment: Ah, they use `sigsuspend()`, not `sigwait()`. Then, as explained in the answer below, it's to prevent race in signal handling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The goal is for the `SIGALRM` sighandler to break the blocking `sigsuspend` call. If the handler isn't blocked, the signal could arrive before the`sigsuspend` call is entered in which case the code (after returning from the handler) will go on to run `sigsuspend` where it'll get deadlocked, waiting for the signal that had already arrived.

It's standard practice to block a signal before atomically unblocking it in `sigsuspend`, and it's done exactly to prevent these kinds of race conditions.